# JQuery and IE7-none of my selectors seem to be working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

In my test sites using FancyBox and VideoJS, none of my popups seem to work in IE7, though they work fine in IE8.
Can anyone suggest a solution?

http://bitstream.ca/beta/
and
http://bitstream.ca/beta2/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `e.preventDefault()` as the first line inside your `a` click handlers.  That will stop the default behavior of your links and let your code execute.